# Django, djblets, datagrid - How to use relations?

Tags: django, datagrid

Let's say I have this model:
models.py

```
class Tool:
   name = models.CharField()
   price = models.DecimalField()

class Storage:
    tool = models.ForeignKey('tools')
    count = models.Integerfield()
```

then in datagrids.py

```
class StorageDataGrid(DataGrid):
    tool = Column()
    count = Column()
    price = ?

def __init__(self, request):
        DataGrid.__init__(self, request, queryset=Storage.objects.all())
        self.default_columns = ['tool', 'count', 'price']
```

The question is, how to define the price column. Or how to have it in a queryset.

Answer (score 1):

So the only way I have found so far is to actually extend the model definition of Storage by:

```
def price(self):
    return tool.price
```

Comment: with such solution there is another problem. sortable=True parameter in the Column definition cannot be use. So still looking how to add price field into instance of model object included in the Queryset. Have tried raw query(LEFT JOIN), but that doesn't work with djblets datagrids, needs to be instance of Queryset.